# Example subsets $B, C \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ and function $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ where $f(B\bigcap C) \subsetneq f(B) \bigcap f(C)$.

Tags: real-analysis

Give an example of subsets $B, C \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ and a function $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ where $f(B\cap C) \subsetneq f(B) \cap f(C)$.

This is a part three to a problem where I previously proved that $f(B \cup C)=f(B) \cup f(C)$ and that $f(B \cap C)  \subseteq f(B) \cap f(C)$.

I know that the subsets $B, C$ should not be equal, and that $f(B\cap C)$ should be smaller than $f(B) \cap f(C)$. I'm thinking of making $f(B\cap C)$ the empty set but am not sure if that is smart? I'm having trouble thinking of how to express these sets and a function that fit these requirements so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Take $B = \lbrace b \rbrace$ and $C = \lbrace c \rbrace$ for some integers $b \neq c$. Now define a function $f \colon \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$, such that $f(b) = f(c)$ (for example a constant function). Then we get what you want as $$f(B \cap C) = f(\emptyset) = \emptyset \subset \lbrace f(b) \rbrace = f(B) \cap f(C).$$

You can also pretty much do the same thing without relying on an empty intersection.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid the empty set, you need to make sure that $f(B\cap C)$ does not hit all of $f(B)\cap f(C)$. So for instance you could take $B=\{1,2\}$, $C=\{2,3\}$, and $f(1)=1$, $f(2)=2$, $f(3)=1$. Then
$$
f(B\cap C)=f(\{2\})=\{2\}, \ \ \ \ \ f(B)\cap f(C)=\{1,2\}. 
$$